# best way to determine if a Linux / Posix RS-485 serial port is idle (ready for transmitting)?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, posix, termios

Greetings all stack people!

I have a master device which talks to several slaves on an RS-485 serial port.
Under certain failure modes ... a slave could run wild or Tx too long.

What is the best way to check the Rx line to see if it is in a mark state long enough for the given baud rate to declare the bus is idle?

Would this work?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>

int fd;
int bytes = 0;
int charTime = 104 * 11;
// assuming:
//   9600 baud, 8 bits,
//   one start, one stop,
//   one bit time minimum inter char spacing.
//   (11 bits total).


int checkIdle(int fd)
{
  ioctl(fd, TCFLSH);
  usleep(charTime * 2);

  // any more activity?
  if (ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes) < 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  if (bytes > 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;    
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: corrected code below "any more activity" ... would still appreciate feed back.

Comment: Deeper: even if code finds "bus is idle" reliably, what is the next step - to use the bus?  Since time elapses between detecting idle and using the bus, the bus may have gone non-idle in-between due to other devices.  Then your transmission may clobber, conflict or get subsumed by others.  The point being, code does not need a super reliable method of detecting idle in isolation as much as a good idle detection  with a following "did  transmit succeed" detection.  A "Would this work?" answer then needs to achieve that overall paired goal.

Comment: I am developing a protocol that is master slave so I just have to make sure the slave is done.

Comment: Experience suggests "just have to make sure the slave is done" is prone to corner problems outside the usual "Master sends command, Slave timely responds".  Consider a tardy slave, errant communuication, master or slave powering up/re-starting in the middle of a conversation,  serial connection/re-connection, etc.  Your call on how robust you want the protocol to be.  You did ask for "best way", yet post lacks info for "best".  Certainly some "Good way" can be guessed though.